# Maximizing the scene after stage is maximized javafx

Tags: java, javafx

When I resize the window, stage, as well as the containing scene is properly resized, but when I click maximize button, only stage is maximized, but not the scene inside. To make matters worse, there are not  methods for manually changing height and width of the scene(those are read only). I also tried to create new scene and put the root element from the old scene inside, but then I get an exception that 2 scenes can't have the same root element. Thanks!

Minimal reproducible example:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 250); 
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                System.out.println("stage width: " + primaryStage.getWidth());
                System.out.println("scene width: " + scene.getWidth());
            }
        });

        primaryStage.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            System.out.println("stage width: " + primaryStage.getWidth());
                System.out.println("scene width: " + scene.getWidth());

        });
    }
```

I first resize a window a bit, and then click maximize. Here's the screenshot of the output:
[image: output]

I marked the moment when I clicked maximize.
Thanks!

Comment: The `Scene` will always fill the `Window`. And as said in `Scene`'s documentation: "_If a Group is used as the root, the contents of the scene graph will be clipped by the scene's width and height and changes to the scene's size (if user resizes the stage) will not alter the layout of the scene graph. If a resizable node (layout Region or Control is set as the root, then the root's size will track the scene's size, causing the contents to be relayed out as necessary_". Your problem is likely related to the layouts you used; please provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Fixing this depends on your parent nodes. If the Parent is an `AnchorPane`, you may need to anchor the bottom, top, left, and right. If the Parent is a VBox or HBox, you may need to use the `VGrow` or `HGrow`. For more details look -> https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

Comment: @Slaw I added a minimal reproducible example. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is flawed. The scene's width is not updated yet when the `maximized` listener is notified. Observing the `width` and `height` properties of both the window and the scene show the scene's dimensions match the window's, minus any window decorations.

Comment: This could probably be avoided if you do not use `Group` as your root node.

Answer (score 1):

As @Slaw pointed out in the comment, scene is resized after the stage, so listening to stage dimension change won't work. I should have listened to scene changes instead. So the correct code is the following:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 250); 
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    scene.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println("stage height: " + primaryStage.getHeight());
        System.out.println("scene height: " + scene.getHeight());
    });

    scene.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        System.out.println("stage width: " + primaryStage.getWidth());
        System.out.println("scene width: " + scene.getWidth());
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot! :D